# WordPress category.php not sorting by category when using query_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm using the `SuperSimple` Theme for a wordpress blog and am trying to customize the `category.php` page. I want to have a big image for the latest post in each category on top of a smaller grid of all the older posts.

So far I have it working the way I want, except the top image (`div id="post1"`) is just the most recent post overall instead of the latest post for the category. Here's one of the category pages: http://meanmargie.com/category/hospitality/

And here's the code I have:

```
<header class="header">
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if ( '' != category_description() ) echo apply_filters( 'archive_meta', '<div class="archive-meta">' . category_description() . '</div>' ); ?>
</header>

<div id="post1">
<?php query_posts('showposts=1'); if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('featured'); } ?>
<div id="post-info"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More</a></div>
<?php endwhile; endif;  wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
<br>

<div id="post2">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('medium'); } ?>
<div id="post-info"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More</a></div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, return the category ID of the category page you are on with `get_query_var('cat')`

```
$category = get_query_var('cat');
  $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

Now, return that id back into [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), using `'cat'=> $cat_id,`. Please note, `showposts` is depreciated, use `posts_per_page` instead

**DO NOT USE** `query_posts`. You should never ever use `query_posts`. It breaks and alters the main query and fails outright in most cases with pagination.

Comment: Thank you, I have it working now.  I'm new to WP so I'm learning the php as I go and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I ended up using:

```
<div id="post1">
<?php //new query to limit number of posts
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query($query_string."&posts_per_page=1&paged=".$paged);
?>
<?php WP_Query; if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('featured'); } ?>
<div class="caption"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div><div class="excerpt"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Read More</a></div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
</div>
```